# how can I correct my settings so I can connect to a web service

Tags: wpf, wcf, web-config

In Visual Studio 2010, I am trying to connect to a web service I have written. I am trying to include the web service project in my WPF solution so I can debug locally, if necessary but, I would also be happy to just publish the web service to my local IIS and connect to it that way.

Here's what happens. I include the web service project in my WPF solution so, I have two projects...the WPF and the WCF web service. I try to add a service reference to my WPF project by opening the Add Service Reference dialog box and clicking the "Discover" button. In the address bar, this uri appears:

```
http://localhost:49185/MyAppSqlServerProvider.svc
```

I give the service a name in the Namespace text box, and then I click "OK". Then, I receive the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

This seems to be a common error. I have found lots of posts about it, and about how to fix it but, I haven't been able to apply those solutions to my situation and get them to work.

Here is the relevant portion of my web.config file

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyAppDataSync.MyAppSqlServerProviderBehavior"
    name="MyAppDataSync.MyAppSqlServerProvider">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyAppDataSync.IMyAppSqlServerProvider" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/MyAppSqlServerProvider/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyAppDataSync.MyAppSqlServerProviderBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="10485760" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

By the way: I am using transport security because I need to use sessions for this service. (ex: [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)])

If anyone can advise me on what I have gotten wrong in my setup, I would really appreciate it. (Why does the "49185" port number get added to the localhost address?)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your base address to specify "https" rather than "http".

Comment: Thanks very much. I had tried so many different approaches that I had created an incompatible hodge-podge of settings. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: No problem - been there myself (and probably will again!)